# is it possible to multiply an append.input within function?

Tags: python-3.x, function, if-statement, input

Looking for help with my function...

the function is trying to help the user add choices on a topic of their choosing into a list.
It is supposed to ask the user how many choices they would like to enter. There must be at least 2, but if the user enters a number >2, i would like the function to generate the appropriate number of prompts for the user to enter total choices - 2 (since the function assumes a minimum of 2), and then keep appending the input onto the same list which will be returned at the end once the user has entered all the input.
I'm having trouble with the last part:  "if number >2..." I don't know how to call choice.append(input(...)) number - 2 times. any help would be appreciated!

```
def first_decisions2():   
    number = int((input("Please enter the number of deciding options (eg. 2 or 
    greater): ")))
    choice = []
    if number <2:
        return "I'm sorry - you didn't enter enough criteria. Please try again."
    if number == 2:
        choice.append(input("Please enter the first choice: ")),
        choice.append(input("Please enter the second choice: "))
        return choice

    if number >2:
        return (number - 2) * choice.append(input("Please enter the next choice: "))

    return choice
```

Comment: Please add more description. It's quite hard to understand what exactly you want to achieve with your function.

Comment: Changed my comments a little bit. hope this clarifies my questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def first_decisions2():   
    number = int((input("Please enter the number of deciding options (eg. 2 or greater): ")))
    choice = []
    if number < 2:
        # return "I'm sorry - you didn't enter enough criteria. Please try again."
        return false

    if number == 2:
        choice.append(input("Please enter the first choice: ")),
        choice.append(input("Please enter the second choice: "))
        return choice

    if number > 2:
        for c in range(0, number - 1):
            choice.append(input("Please enter the next choice: "))
        return choice

    return choice
```

I would loop through the number chosen asking for input each time like so